# how can select a file from my file folder in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

how can browse a file (any type) from file manager. i am trying to using this code

```
Intent pickFileIntent = new Intent();
pickFileIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
pickFileIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
pickFileIntent.setType("*/*");
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(pickFileIntent,
                           getText(R.string.choosefile_title));
startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, PICK_FILE_REQUEST);
```

this code is open the gallery and select the picture but  file not browse.
my LogCat error is

```
 02-19 16:46:19.846: E/ActivityThread(512): Failed to find provider info for com.navjagpal.filesharer.FileProvider
```

i am beginner in android.please help me with a sample code .
thanks in advance.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify full path in Authorities tag in manifest file ( SearchableDictionary sample code in SDK).

```
<provider android:name=".DictionaryProvider"
       android:authorities="com.example.android.searchabledict.DictionaryProvider"
```

Comment: Your <provider> element needs to be in the application, as it is the one with the ContentProvider. The fact that the Java class implementing that ContentProvider happens to be in an Android library project does not change the fact that the hosting app is the one responsible for that provider.

Comment: <provider android:name=".FileProvider" android:authorities="com.navjagpal.fileshare.FileProvider"
   android:exported="false" />

  <provider android:name=".FileSharingProvider" android:authorities="com.navjagpal.fileshare.FileSharingProvider"
    android:exported="false"/>

Comment: @NarenderSharma can you check this code http://code.google.com/p/android-file-dialog/ may be this can give you some pointers